# How to pass kotlin FloatArray to flutter?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to implement some kotlin native code so I have a `FloatArray` which I need to pass to flutter side.

Here is what it looks like,

kotlin code snippets

```
private var sampleData : FloatArray? = null

fun someFunction(){
// add data to sampleData
}

fun getData(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        result.success(sampleData)
    }
```

dart code snippet

```
Future<void> getData() async {
    var result = await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('sampleData');
    print('type -> ${result.runtimeType}');
  }
```

When I print on both platforms it does print data on both platforms but on the flutter side when I check the runtimeType it always says `List<Object?>`.

So how can I pass FloatArray so that object is the relevant type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `List.from()` like this,

```
Future<List<double>> getData() async {
    var result = await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('sampleData');
    return List<double>.from(result ?? []);
  }
```